# How do I find the common variable?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

A group of 724 students has the following characteristics:
185 live on campus and major in psychology;
50 live off campus and major in psychology;
190 live off campus and do not major in psychology.

The following questions refer to these students.

(a) How many of the students either live on campus or major in psychology?

[I am stumped after inputing these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBGjP.jpg)

Comment: The Venn diagram that you show is not the best representation for this : the intersections between "on-campus" and "off-campus" are empty ; same for "psych". The Caroll diagrams https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carroll_diagram are best suited for what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $C$ denote the group of those who live on campus and $P$ those who study Psychology. Then we can represent your problem as:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

\begin{array}{c|cc}
 & \text{C} & \neg \,C  \\
\hline
P     & 185 & 50 \\
\neg P & (299) & 190 
\end{array}